# Constrains never satisfied (iOS, Autolayouts)

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, ios7, nslayoutconstraint, xcode5

This is my first project using Storyboard and Autolayout. I have no idea what I am missing.

I have a table with a prototype cell, in which I want to put an image. I want this image to be 10 px from top and left side, and be 20px x 30px big. So I put constraints as follows:

[image]

Because constraints lighted up orange (don't even know why), I deleted them and asked Xcode to put the constraints itself. This is what I got:

[image]

Not only the constraints are redundant, but also they are orange! What do I do wrong here?

---

**EDIT**

As I noticed, it's a bigger problem. Xcode Version 5.0 (5A11365x) has some problems with calculating constraints, shows warnings "Missing constraints" when these "missing" constraints are set, or "empty errors" (there is a warning "Missing constraint", but there is no body text of the warning), keeps lagging heavily when I pick a storyboard file from Project Navigator.

Looks like it's an Xcode issue - after all, it's still a Preview version.

Comment: You've got Xcode 5 so it's safe to say you have access to the WWDC Videos. You should watch the Autolayout one to know why they are orange and what to do about them; and the three from WWDC 12. Don't just guess at this stuff - use the resources available to you.

Comment: I did watched all the videos related to Autolayouts. Apart from that, the approach I take is correct - first image has almost the same constraints in every tutorial I've watched. Except they are orange, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Xcode 5, looks like you had proper constraints in place.  Could the frame location need to be updated?

[image]

Comment: As it's not the real resolution to my problem, I won't accept it, but I'll upvote, because indeed updating frames fixes the problem of "correctly set, yet orange" constraints.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I am using uitableviewcell in a xib and looks like Xcode5 is expecting an iPhone's width, when designing on an iPad's cell I got several warnings about view's origins that disappear if the cell is changed to an iPhone's one.